# Reemplazar texto con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Q tal, no se si será posible.. pero; quiero hacer esto: mejor lo explico con imágenes veamos por favor..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ven la parte seleccionada en amarillo? bueno quiero que esa parte (menos la parte roja) se pegue, reemplazando lo que indica la flecha.. manteniendo la extensión (.zip)

Yo se que por ahí lo que pido es imposible pero al menos pregunto.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body" data-loading-overlay="" style="">
        <table id="list-files" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="35">
                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="">
                  <label for="select-all-files"></label>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>File</th>
              <th>Size</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input name="files[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="0"><label></label></div>
              </td>
              <td class="pt-none pb-none">
                <div>
                  <div class="pull-left mt-xs mr-xs">IObit.Driver.Booster.6.2.PRO.v6.2.0.198.ML.Repack.By.Thebig[b9b.com] / </div>
                  <div style="overflow:hidden"><input class="form-control input-sm m-none" style="background-color: transparent" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="b9b.com.txt"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>30.0 iB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input name="files[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="1"><label></label></div>
              </td>
              <td class="pt-none pb-none">
                <div>
                  <div class="pull-left mt-xs mr-xs">IObit.Driver.Booster.6.2.PRO.v6.2.0.198.ML.Repack.By.Thebig[b9b.com] / </div>
                  <div style="overflow:hidden"><input class="form-control input-sm m-none" style="background-color: transparent" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="IObit Driver Booster 6.2 PRO (v6.2.0.198) ML Repack By Thebig.zip"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>17.4 MiB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input name="files[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="2"><label></label></div>
              </td>
              <td class="pt-none pb-none">
                <div>
                  <div class="pull-left mt-xs mr-xs">IObit.Driver.Booster.6.2.PRO.v6.2.0.198.ML.Repack.By.Thebig[b9b.com] / </div>
                  <div style="overflow:hidden"><input class="form-control input-sm m-none" style="background-color: transparent" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="IObit Driver Booster Repack By Thebig.nfo"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>5.1 KiB</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="loading-overlay" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;">
          <div class="bounce-loader">
            <div class="bounce1"></div>
            <div class="bounce2"></div>
            <div class="bounce3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="panel">
      <header class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title"></h2>
      </header>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que pretendo es básicamente que el título de (1) se copie y reemplace en (2) manteniendo el formato y eliminando en este caso `[b9b.com] /`

***Quedando así:***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Copia lo marcado omitiendo `[b9b.com] /`
2. Lo pega ahí reemplazando el original
3. Dejando como resultado lo marcado con su respectiva extensión (sea cual sea)

No tengo un `script` pero me gustaría que me comentaran si se puede hacer algo así y me den unos ejemplos (por favor tengan en cuenta que se casi nada de `script's`) y amigos es para **tampermonkey**

Por último dejo un DEMO del `HTML` para que si pueden introduzcan algunos `scripts` haber como se hace
[JSFiddle para probar los scripts](https://jsfiddle.net/qwertyip/8k9pfjd1/6/)

Bueno espero alguna ayuda nos vemos

Ah, algunas observaciones:

- El orden de los elementos (.zip, .nfo, txt) suele cambiar
- No importa si el reemplazo pega en todos los input lo mismo con sus
  respectivos formatos
- Es para ejecutar con Tampermonkey
- Mejor con JQuery, otros métodos no son compatibles
- La idea es que sirva tanto para este ejemplo como para otros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con $('.pull-left') seleccionas todos los elementos que contengan la clase pull-left, el código itera sobre cada elemento y extraes el titulo con

```
const titulo =$(this).text().replace('[b9b.com] /','').trim();
```

la función replace busca la cadena especificada en este caso "[b9b.com] /", la remplaza por "" y por ultimo le quita los espacios al inicio y al final con la funcion trim()

```
$(this).next().find('input')
```

la función .next() lo que hace es buscar las etiquetas que se encuentren al mismo nivel y dentro de ellas busca los elementos input con la función .find()

la función .each() itera sobre los resultados de la expresión anterior permitiendote selecciona elemento por elemento, extraer el valor de cada uno con la funcion .val(), después dividir su valor a un array usando el caracter ¨.¨ con la función .split(), la funcion .pop() extrae el ultimo elemento del arreglo que en este caso es la extensión del archivo y la función .trim() quita los espacios iniciales y finales que pudiera contener, el resultado se guarda en la constante extencion así:

```
const extencion =$(this).val().split('.').pop().trim();
```

finalmente asignamos el titulo filtrado y la extensión al valor de cada input con:

```
$(this).val(`${titulo}.${extencion}`);
```

Aquí está el código completo:

```
$('.pull-left').each(function(){
  const titulo =$(this).text().replace('[b9b.com] /','').trim();
  $(this).next().find('input').each(function(){
        const extencion =$(this).val().split('.').pop().trim();
            $(this).val(`${titulo}.${extencion}`);
  })
})
```

Comment: esto claramente no responde a la pregunta y es mas un comentario de que hacer, por tal razón no debería ir en la zona de respuestas, favor de revisar [answer]

Comment: como te decía arriba tómate el tiempo de leer [answer] pues hacer solo comentarios es incorrecto, ahora poner solo código también es incorrecto, deberás darle editar y añadir una explicación

Comment: Uff amigo.. recontra perfecto!! muchisimas gracias por tomarte este tiempo para ayudar. estoy eternamente agradecido con vos, el codigo funciona perfecto y la explicación lo vale en cada caractér. usted sabe! jaja

Comment: amigos como podría agregar mas palabras para quitar en `const titulo =$(this).text().replace('[b9b.com] /','').trim();`? por ejemplo si quiero quitar los espacios por puntos u otra frase o simple caracter especial?

Comment: añade otra funcion al final de la expresión .replace("tu caracter o frase","tu texto de remplazo")

Comment: lo hice. otra vez muy genial lo tuyo amigo, muchas gracias